# VBA Solver code issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using a loop is which I access the excel solver. But every time the solver solves an optimization problem, I have to click ok. I tried record macro, but no code came up when I click the OK button. I will always accept the solution suggested by the solver.I do not want to keep pressing Ok button all the time. There could potentially be 2000+ optimization problems being solved. Is there a way of making this work?

Also, is there a way of solving unbalanced transportation problem is a solver without having to make dummy supplies or demand nodes?

Thank you.

The codes is as follows:
SolverReset

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$B$18", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, _
ByChange:="$M$5:$T$12", Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"

SolverAdd CellRef:="$U$5:$U$12", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$V$5:$V$12"

SolverAdd CellRef:="$M$13:$T$13", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$M$14:$T$14"
SolverSolve
```

Comment: Could you please share your code..

Comment: SolverReset
    
    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$18", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, _
    ByChange:="$M$5:$T$12", Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$U$5:$U$12", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$V$5:$V$12"
    
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$M$13:$T$13", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$M$14:$T$14"
    SolverSolve

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.solver.com/excel-solver-solversolve-function) at Solver.com (the website of the company that made the Solver add-in) contains:

> SolverSolve(UserFinish, ShowRef)
>
> UserFinish   Optional Variant. True to return the results without
>   displaying the Solver Results dialog box. False or omitted to return
>   the results and display the Solver Results dialog box.
>
> ShowRef   Optional Variant. You can pass the name of a macro (as a
>   string) as the ShowRef argument. This macro is then called, in lieu of
>   displaying the Show Trial Solution dialog box, whenever Solver pauses
>   for any of the reasons listed below.

Thus it seems that you need to replace the line `SolverSolve` by

```
SolverSolve True
```

But -- it is probably a better idea to read the rest of the documentation about the return value of `SolverSolve` and perhaps do something like

```
retValue = SolverSolve(True)
```

and then check `retValue` with some error-handling if it isn't one of the values which correspond to a successful run. People can be optimistic. Code should be pessimistic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Great advice!

Comment: @John Coleman Totally agree, super advice!!